# Slow WiFi, fast Ethernet after switching ISP

Tags: wireless-networking, ethernet

Recently I have switched ISPs. In both cases the CAT5 cable goes directly into MY wifi router (ASUS RT-N66U), with no remote management. However, after the switch, WiFi speed has decreased considerably, although the router remained the same.
When I do a wired connection to one of the router’s LAN ports, I get the expected speed/bandwidth (100Mbps). On wireless however, the speed is almos 5x slower.

I have tried a different wireless router, different wireless clients (Mac, Windows, iPhone), results are the same. I have even tested live switching the WAN cable between ISPs while both were active, and the change in wifi speed is also immediate.

**Edit**: I am located in Europe, and for measuring the speed I'm downloading a 1000mb test file hosted by a European network provider (Leaseweb). I also have a VPS hosted there so I could install `iperf` if necessary. I am not using ISP provided DNS settings, but Cloudflare / Google instead, which also doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Did you test your WiFi speed before the change? Or did you only notice after?

Comment: @CustomX hello, it is written in the question “speed has decreased considerably”. Also, when plugging the old ISPs cable, the wifi speed goes back to normal.

Comment: It makes no sense WiFi would be slower, if you use the exact same hardware and only the ISP has changed. Are you in the same network when connected wirelessly and wired?

Comment: @CustomX yes I am, and I know it doesn’t make sense, that’s why the question

Comment: Can you explain precisely how you are measuring the speed?

Comment: @develroot What router, what ISP(s), is the router channel changing on restart or applying a config from a remote management server provided by either isp? We need some more details

Comment: @user3788685 i have updated the question. The ISP part seems irrelevant, because  it's unlikely anyone here lives in my country (Moldova). The router isn't changing channels and as I have mentioned earlier, the speed difference can be noticed just by hot-switching the WAN cable, no need to restart the router.

Comment: Could you please provide some ping statistics (1-2 minutes should do) from a WIFI device to your router IP and then from the WIFI device to an external location (Google.com etc...) this is just to help identify any packet loss. Could you please also confirm your firmware version, I cannot find a demo of ASUS RT-N66U, is the layout similar to this - https://event.asus.com/2012/nw/dummy_ui/en/

Comment: @develroot - whilst hot switching the WAN cable allows it to connect to the new ISP this does not say that any cached data in the router has been cleared. To confirm have you tried powering down the router and then changing the WAN connection and powering back on after leaving the device powered down for at least 30 seconds?

Comment: @CraftyB I have no packet loss, as reported by MTR tool. I have also tried restarting the router to exclude any "cached data". The router part also seems irrelevant because I have tried 3 different routers (including a dumb Wi-Fi access point that has 1 WAN port and nothing else), and the results were the same - slow wifi on new isp.

Answer (score 1):

The difference might lie in the different nature of the TCP packets that are sent for
wired and wireless communications.

The 
[MTU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit)
for wireless networks is said to be larger.
The article
[Wireless Packet Sizes](https://smallbusiness.chron.com/wireless-packet-sizes-28283.html)
claims it to be 2,312 bytes including packet headers.
This is larger than the Ethernet recommendation for wired networks,
which is 1,500 bytes.
Note that communication with the ISP might require adding an extra header
of eight bytes which reduces the maximum packet size to 1,492 bytes
(which was also the optimal size I found in some testing done some years ago).

Wikipedia
[Maximum transmission unit (MTU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit)
gives more details:

> **IP MTUs for common media**
>
> [image]

Possibly the infrastructure of your ISP badly handles large packets,
when it needs to split up into smaller packets to pass through the ISP's network.
The process as done inside the ISP's network might be so inefficiently
programmed as to slow down the transfer speed.

This conjuncture that the problem lies in larger TCP packet size is perhaps
supported by the fact that wireless traffic traveling within your network
is not reduced in speed.
Seemingly, your router better handles such packets.

Check if your router can be configured to limit packet size to 1,492
(or less) bytes, for both wired and wireless.
If it is not possible, try to get help from your ISP Support,
or possibly even change ISP (again) if their infrastructure is so badly
configured (or change the router).

User @DanielK pointed to the article
[Changing the MTU size in Windows Vista, 7 or 8](https://support.zen.co.uk/kb/Knowledgebase/Changing-the-MTU-size-in-Windows-Vista-7-or-8)
where these commands were suggested, running in an elevated
Command Prompt:

**List all network interface ids:**

```
netsh interface ipv4 show subinterface
```

**Set the MTU Size:**

```
netsh interface ipv4 set subinterface "interface-id" mtu=<size> store=persistent
```

Reboot is required after this last command.

This might also be required to be done for `ipv6`.
If it works for you, then this is a workaround that can let you keep
your current ISP (still at the cost of some throughput).

Comment: @develroot If you try this, and it works, please report back to let us know.

Comment: @harrymc I can not see the reasoning behind this. Router's WAN MTU is 1500, meaning that all packets that are sent to ISP have a MTU of 1500, regardless of the source (wifi or ethernet). And you can not set the MTU "for both wired and wireless" on the router side, because MTU is a client setting, (hence the WAN MTU setting). Am I wrong?

Comment: @develroot I think this is an interesting approach. How about you capture some wireless traffic using a sniffer and see if the packets are indeed larger than wired packets?

Comment: I concur with @DanielK. Without some sniffing it would not be possible to know what is really going on here. It might help to know the make & model of the router in question.

Comment: @DanielK Wireshark reports all packets have a length of 1500, with TCP flags 0x4000 (Don't fragment)

Comment: Strange, because apart from package size, I can't see any other difference that could affect wireless transmission speed toward the ISP. I wonder if Wireshark's virtual adapter itself can have some effect on the result.

Comment: @develroot **all packets**? meaning you cannot see any difference between wired and wireless packets? Are you measuring this upstream of the wireless access point (i.e. nearer the WAN)?

Comment: @DanielK sorry I meant the **maximum** length of the packets. There are others with different values, but no more than 1500.

Comment: @develroot as an experiment could you alter the MTU on a wireless test client to, say, 1400 bytes? This article could help https://support.zen.co.uk/kb/Knowledgebase/Changing-the-MTU-size-in-Windows-Vista-7-or-8

Comment: There are many sources saying the same as my answer. For example, [Wikipedia Maximum transmission unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_transmission_unit) says: "IEEE 802.11 Wi-Fi (WLAN) - 2304 - The maximum MSDU size is 2304 before encryption". This is the possible MTU, not necessarily the one your adapter uses, so the answer by @develroot might be a good test, and if it works, then also a good workaround.